# How to load sklearn datasets manually?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to load a larger dataset from the `sklearn` datatsets (California housing prices). Using the default command does not work for me due to proxy issues (the dataset download corrupted).

```
d = datasets.fetch_california_housing()
```

After downloading it, I place it in the directory found by `datasets.get_data_home()` (`/home/username/scikit_learn_data/`) and place the files in that folder and also in the cal_housing folder in that directory and in the CaliforniaHousing folder to check all the options. I also tried specifying the custom location with data_home parameter.

```
d = datasets.fetch_california_housing(data_home='/home/username/scikit_learn_data/')
```

Nothing works.

How can I load the dataset manually?

Note:
To test if the manual loading works, please set `download_if_missing=False`

Comment: Have you tried this? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_files.html

Comment: Hmm.. the datatset comes in form of two files in particular format, which should be loaded together, so not sure if it would work.

Comment: Can you show your code and the error?

Comment: The error is that the dataset is not found and I described the code above. I also added another line of code.

Comment: How and what did you download and where did you put it? To use `fetch_california_housing`, there should be a file `cal_housing.pkz` present inside the `data_home` directory

Comment: Yes, right. I tried it. I tried different ways described in the question. Nothing works as mentioned. If there is a way that works for you (manual loading), please share.

Comment: What file did you download and where you placed it?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, since my developing environment cannot access the web, so that the default 'download_if_missing' of course could not work.

If you follow the URL, you will be able to save a cal_housing.tgz file from the web. But the fetch_california_housing method actually does some more conversion in the default download_if_missing fork and expects a pkz-file (as Vivek already pointed out above). I found a workaround to create that .pkz file here: (https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/issues/221). I repost Auréliens answer (kudos!) here:

Quote:
"
I can give you a workaround:

Manually download the data using your web browser: https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/5976036
Make sure the downloaded file is named cal_housing.tgz.
Execute the following Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import tarfile
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.datasets.base import _pkl_filepath, get_data_home

archive_path = "cal_housing.tgz" # change the path if it's not in the current directory
data_home = get_data_home(data_home=None) # change data_home if you are not using ~/scikit_learn_data
if not os.path.exists(data_home):
    os.makedirs(data_home)
filepath = _pkl_filepath(data_home, 'cal_housing.pkz')

with tarfile.open(mode="r:gz", name=archive_path) as f:
    cal_housing = np.loadtxt(
        f.extractfile('CaliforniaHousing/cal_housing.data'),
        delimiter=',')
    # Columns are not in the same order compared to the previous
    # URL resource on lib.stat.cmu.edu
    columns_index = [8, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 0]
    cal_housing = cal_housing[:, columns_index]

    joblib.dump(cal_housing, filepath, compress=6)
```

After that you should be able to use fetch_california_housing() without any problem. This works because the code above is what fetch_california_housing() does the first time you call it, after it downloaded the data: it prepares the data and saves it in cache in Scikit-Learn's data directory (which is by default $HOME/scikit_learn_data). The next times you call fetch_california_housing(), it just loads the data from this directory, so it will not need to download it.

Hope this helps,
Aurélien
"

End of Auréliens Quote

Comment: brilliant solution, worked for me!
if this line ```from sklearn.externals import joblib``` doesn't work, use directly ```import joblib```

Comment: For users coming from year 2023 or if you are using sklearn version 1.0.2 or above, minor changes you should apply : `import joblib`
`from sklearn.datasets._base import _pkl_filepath, get_data_home`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

1. Download the *cal_housing.tgz* file manually as described above and copy it e.g. to C:\Temp.
2. Open the file [YOUR_PYTHON_PATH]\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\base.py
3. In the function *_fetch_remote()* comment out the line *urlretrieve(remote.url, file_path)*. Then python don't try to download the file *cal_housing.tgz* again.
4. Start *d=datasets.fetch_california_housing(data_home='C://tmp//')* and the file *cal_housing_py3.pkz* will be created.
5. Then you should take back step 3.

I know this is a little bid ugly because you have to change an internal python package file. But it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.datasets import california_housing
data = california_housing.fetch_california_housing()
calf_hous_df = pd.DataFrame(data= data.data, columns=data.feature_names)    
calf_hous_df.head(5)

Out[105]: 
   MedInc  HouseAge  AveRooms  AveBedrms  Population  AveOccup  Latitude  \
0  8.3252      41.0  6.984127   1.023810       322.0  2.555556     37.88   
1  8.3014      21.0  6.238137   0.971880      2401.0  2.109842     37.86   
2  7.2574      52.0  8.288136   1.073446       496.0  2.802260     37.85   
3  5.6431      52.0  5.817352   1.073059       558.0  2.547945     37.85   
4  3.8462      52.0  6.281853   1.081081       565.0  2.181467     37.85   

   Longitude  
0    -122.23  
1    -122.22  
2    -122.24  
3    -122.25  
4    -122.25
```

Comment: Explain it please!

Answer (score 0):

[Oceansunfish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55040662/16760102) does work for me.

However, You may change this line

> `from sklearn.datasets.base import _pkl_filepath, get_data_home`

to

> `from sklearn.datasets._base import _pkl_filepath, get_data_home`

because the source code may have been changed.

I had better add a comment below the original answer but I don't have enough reputation to do so.